# Images not loading when deploying streamlit app on GCP

Tags: gcc, python-3.8, streamlit

I created a streamlit app for data science. The user uploads an image and gets an output with an image displayed, but after deploying the app I'm getting zero rather than an image.

```py
import streamlit as st

@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_image(out):
    if out=='yes':
        im = PIL.Image.open("images/yes.jpg")
        return im

dis = load_image(output)
st.image(dis, channels="RGB)
```

but after deploying I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by transforming the image (OpenCV, pillow ...) into bytes

```
import base64
import cv2
import streamlit as st
retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img )
binf = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode()
st.image("data:image/png;base64,%s"%binf, channels="BGR", use_column_width=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably already solved, but I fixed it using

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st

arr_img = plt.imread(absoulte_path_to_img)
st.image(arr_img, channels="RGB")
```